# How to 'throw' my own 'onChange' event in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component for 'gender' selection that has two radiobuttons (male, female).

```
function GenderPicker(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //female
        onChange={props.OnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //male
        onChange={props.OnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
    <>
  )
}
```

Now when I change the state of the radiobuttons catches the onChange event, but in the event I get the object (currentTarget) that was clicked (either 'female' or 'male').

Is it possible to 'throw' my own event/object?
Something like this:

```
function GenderPicker(props) {
  function handleOnGenderChange(e) {
    // make here my own event/object based with the value based on the selection (e.currentTarget.checked)

    props.OnGenderChange()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //female
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //male
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
    <>
  )
}
```

I hope someone can help me out here. Or maybe there is a beter/easier way?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see too main options. First one is defining a `value` in the radio button. You catch the event and then call the callback with whatever object you want, using the data from the `value` property. This assumes that your `Radio` component behaves exactly like a normal HTML radio input.

```js
function GenderPicker(props) {
  const handleOnGenderChange = event => {
    // Example of object you might want to send in the callback.
    const callbackPayload = {
      name: event.currentTarget.value, // "male" or "female"
      checked: event.currentTarget.checked,
    }

    props.OnGenderChange(callbackPayload)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Radio
        value="male"
        id={props.id} //female
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
      <Radio
        value="female"
        id={props.id} //male
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange}
        ....
      />
    <>
  )
}
```

The other option would be to create different functions on render time, depending on the radio button that's being clicked. You can do this by defining a function that returns another function based on which radio button is rendered.

```js
function GenderPicker(props) {
  const handleOnGenderChange = name => event {
    // Example of object you might want to send in the callback.
    const callbackPayload = {
      name, // "male" or "female"
      checked: event.currentTarget.checked,
    }

    props.OnGenderChange()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //female
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange("male")}
        ....
      />
      <Radio
        id={props.id} //male
        onChange={handleOnGenderChange("female"}
        ....
      />
    <>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about that, but then the response is not like 'other ' onChange events like containing 'currentTarget' for example. Is it possible to make 'GenderPicker' the currentTarget which hold a value 'male' or 'female' or do I have to build an object with nested [currentTarget: {id: ..., value: ...}} ?

Comment: If you need a custom object in the response, then yes, you need to build a custom object... I'm not sure what's confusing you.

Comment: Well, it's not really confusing me, and the onChange function at a higher order is only checking for currentTarget.id and currentTarget.value so it would probably be easier to just make the object myself. I just thought, maybe there is a beter/proper way to do this, where there is actually an component in the event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to work with name attribute for the tag input type radio. 
Check this codesandbox and let me know if it was what you expect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-worker-idumd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed. Also thanks for the demo. If i give them both the same id, I could check for the id and read the value. Because @RicardoLopes answer was more close to what I asked, I will accept his answer as the answer. No I have to pick which way I will use. Regards

Comment: No problem. Regards